# Print pdf file using c#, code behind and send value to javascript to generate print popup

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, pdf

I am working on a c# asp.net project in which, I have to print a PDF file from a directory where there are dozens of files. 
I can pick the file from directory but I am not able to print that file by generating a pop up.

Does any one knows how to pass that file from back end code to java script so that It can show popup and ask for print?

P.S:I can not post code here due to PHI issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open your PDF to window, get that window form Javascript,

call javascript function,

```
OpenPrintPopUP(){
var display_setting="toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,menubar=no, scrollbars=no,width=650, height=850, left=100, top=25"

var prntWindow = window.open("","",display_setting);
prntWindow.document.write(printContent);
prntWindow.document.close();
prntWindow.focus();
prntWindow.print();

prntWindow.close();
}
```

Comment: DDave Thanks for your reply but the problem is how can i pass the file name from back end code to "path" in  window.open(path).

Comment: @user3061917 can't you save the path to some hidden variables in c# and access those from JS? here your code could have helped more

Comment: ok its good point to store that value in hidden field then can you please tell me how can i pass that hidden field value to JS?

Comment: SET ::- <input type="hidden" name="ctlAxisName" id="MainContent_txtXAxisName" value="Days" />
GET ::- var xAxis = document.getElementById("ctlAxisName");

Comment: Thanks alot @DDave